# Where can I find photo frame suppliers in the UK?

Tags: framing

I am looking to setup a photography print business. Does anyone know of any suppliers that can provide frames for 18 x 12" photos? Ideally it would be good if they were UK based.

Comment: Someone should make a sticky about this...

Comment: @MichaelK — a sticky? We ain't got no stickies. This isn't a bulletin board.

Comment: I know... therefore I thought it's clear that I meant something like this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-device

Comment: "Community wiki". That's a decent approach for questions which are just lists of facts (as this might indeed be). It's less good (that is, not good at all) for answers which include experiences with suppliers and subjective analysis of why one might pick one over the other. And, it's _that_ which makes it useful to have answers on Stack Exchange rather than just telling people [do a google search for "photo frames uk"](http://www.google.com/search?q=photo+frames+uk). CW fact-lists can work, but usually stagnate and become useless, as there's no incentive or responsibility to maintain them.

Comment: We don' need no stiiinkeen stiikies  ;)   - also: great question. Hope it gets a great answer.

Comment: I am a manufacturer please contact me. aytrademanchester@hotmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.readymadepictureframe.com/ - wide variety of frames in various colours and styles

Comment: Does anyone have any experience of the quality of the frames from this supplier?

Answer (score 2):

I use [Picture Frames Direct](http://www.picture-frames-direct.com/)

Very good in price, mostly glass and they have a huge range, and when they deliver the frames are wrapped in heaps of bubble wrap so very well protected while in transit.

If you order over the phone, which is what I do, you will get sound advice as well as being able to ask lots of questions, change the colour and apeture of the mount or even order double mounts.

If you are looking for Quality and aren't worried about price then [Kenro](http://www.kenro.co.uk) are another option, however they supply only to professional photography shops and studios, and supply in bulk, when I first ordered I needed to order a min of 5 of the same frames.